# PhpStorm/WebStorm and standard linting errors

Tags: javascript, coding-style, phpstorm, standards, eslint

I've just moved to PhpStorm from Sublime as it seems to have a lot of ways to make my life as a dev easier.

One thing though, in my company we use Standard (https://github.com/feross/standard) for good or worse, but I had I think not even configured Sublime much to actually highlight the errors in a way that I can't miss them and solve them earlier in the process:

[image: sublime linter cryout]

Now I'm trying to get the same thing going on in PhpStorm, but can't figure out how to "throw" the errors in that software.

I have followed this: 
https://github.com/feross/standard/blob/master/docs/webstorm.md, and particularly step 6, I have also modified the theme to set the errors more explicit:

[image: error editor]

but I get no highlights:

[image: no warnings phpstorm]

has anybody solved that could guide me?
Thanks

Comment: If you're a Webstorm/PhpStorm users, [vote for `standard` to be one of the default styles](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-17331) built into the app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it to work:

The trick was to specify that ESLint should use `eslintrc.json` from `eslint-config-standard` package.

This can be done in: `Preferences > Languages & Frameworks > Javascript > Code Quality Tools > ESLint` and use configuration file (find it in your node modules)

Answer (score 0):

File >> Settings >> Editor >> Code Style >> JavaScript >> Whatever u wanna do u can do it here, from highlighting unused variables to spaces and brackets. No need to download any module or to modify any existing file.

Comment: This is interesting but still doesn't solve my issue. It's not about the code style itself (which the XML provided by Standard already enables), but more about throwing/highlighting (I want them super explicit) the error on the code-style issue.